# Why to use btford/angular-socket-io: Socket.IO component for AngularJS?

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, socket.io, mean-stack, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing an hybrid mobile app using ionic framework.

The app has a feature of chat (one to one chat). My friend insisting to use  [btford/angular-socket-io](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io) for development.

Is it really necessary to use the library, can't we achieve same normally by following simple chat app using socket-io.js

Please guide.